# Arch/Asahi not resizing to screen resolution

Tags: arch-linux

I am brand new to Linux, and just installed Asahi Linux (which is based on Arch) on my M1 Mac Mini. I believe it uses KDE Plasma. My screen (an LG 49WL95C-WE) is an ultra-wide 5120x1440 (aspect ratio 32:9). I've run `pacman -Syu` to ensure everything is up to date.

My problem is that the system is treating my screen like a 1920x1080 display. When I go into Display Configuration under System Settings it indicates that this "is the only resolution supported by this display."

After some research, I tried setting a custom resolution:

```
$ cvt 5120 1440 60
# 5120x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 624.50 MHz
Modeline "5120x1440_60.00"  624.50  5120 5496 6048 6976  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync

$ sudo xrandr --newmode "5120x1440_60.00"  624.50  5120 5496 6048 6976  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"
None-1

$ sudo xrandr --addmode None-1 5120x1440_60.00
```

When I do this, the resolution now shows up as an option in Display Configuration. However, when I select it, the following vague error message appears: "Outputs could not be saved due to error."

I also tried the above steps with a 3840x1080 resolution. With this setting there is no error message. The screen flashes once, but there is no change in the resolution.

Any help would be much appreciated as my system is unusable at the the current resolution.

Comment: Noticed in the System Log the following error message when I try to resize the resolution: "kf.coreaddons: "Could not load plugin from kcm_kscreen: The shared library was not found."